# 親要素の値からjQueryでRadioのインデックスを取得したい

Tags: jquery, html

以下の様なhtmlからjQueryを使用し、Radioのインデックスを取得したいです。
Optionタグのvalueからインデックスを取得しようとしています。例えばvalue=S1の場合、インデックスは0, value=S2、またはS3の場合は1となります。

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="radio-group-wrapper">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="MT" value="ST" checked="checked">TEST1
      </label>
      <select name="SID" class="select-sid">
        <option value="S1">BASIC</option></option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="radio-group-wrapper">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="MT" value="ST" checked="checked">TEST2 
      </label>
      <select name="SID" class="select-sid">
        <option value="S2">OP1</option></option>
        <option value="S3">OP2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

試しに以下のjQueryを試しましたが取得できませんでした。

```
var index =
$('option[value=S1]:first').parent('select[name="sid"]').prev('label').children('input[name="MT"]:checked').index();
```

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`index()` は要素の集合に適用するメソッドで、その集合の中で何番目か知りたい要素は引数で与えます。
`option[value=S1]:first`の先祖の`.radio-group-wrapper`が文書全体で何番目の `.radio-group-wrapper`か知りたい場合は、以下の様になります。

```js
var index = $('.radio-group-wrapper').index(
    $('option[value=S1]:first').parents(".radio-group-wrapper"));
```

分けて書くとこんな感じです。

```js
// 'option[value=S1]:first' で選択される要素の集合（一つ）
var option = $('option[value=S1]:first');

// option の親の集合の中で、'.radio-group-wrapper'で選択される要素の集合（一つの予定）
var radio = option.parents('.radio-group-wrapper');

// 文書全体で、'.radio-group-wrapper' で選択される要素の集合
var all_radio = $('.radio-group-wrapper');

// all_radio 内での radio のインデックス
var index = all_radio.index(radio);
```